# How to send header to remote site via anyorigin.com using ajax request?

Tags: javascript, ajax, user-agent

I am trying to send customized header to a remote website using anyorigin.com service but for some reason the user agent header is not passed to remote site!

Prove that header is not send comes from response i get back from www.whatsmyuseragent.com which shows different user agent then the one i send!

could any one tell me why user agent header is not passed to remote website ?

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://anyorigin.com/jquery-1.4.2.min.js"></script>

<script>
$.ajax({
    url: 'http://anyorigin.com/get?url=http://www.whatsmyuseragent.com/&callback=?',
    xhr: {
             withCredentials: true
         },
    type: 'GET',
    dataType: "json",
    success: displayAll,
    beforeSend: setHeader
    });
function displayAll(data){
   // alert(data.contents);
document.myform2.outputtext2.value = data.contents ;
}

function setHeader(xhr){
xhr.setRequestHeader("User-Agent","Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; U; CPU like Mac OS X; en) AppleWebKit/420.1 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/3.0 Mobile/3B48b Safari/419.3");
}
</script>
</head>

<body>
<br>
<form id="myform2" name="myform2" action="./5.php?Id=&title=" method="post">
<td><textarea rows="14" cols="15" name="outputtext2" style="width: 99%;"></textarea>    </td>
</form>
</html>
```

Comment: I would imagine the issue is most likely on anyorigin's end. They probably aren't forwarding all the headers. Have you tried contacting them and asking about it?

Comment: Thanks for reply. I coludn't find a help forum for the service they provide to ask them about it! Do you know how to contact them?

Comment: I looked at the domain's whois records which would indicate zelexi at gmail.com is the administrator's email address.